# Unity зависает на функции Find

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот код, который выполняется:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace DeadLords.Controller
{
    public class FlashlightController : BaseController
    {
        private Light _light;
        private Transform battery;     //Корпус батарейки
        private Image[] batteryFill;    //Заполненность батарейки
        private int batteryCount;
        private float dischargeTime, rechargeTime;

        #region Unity time
        private void Awake()
        {
            _light = GameObject.Find("Flashlight").GetComponent<Light>();
            battery = GameObject.Find("Battery").GetComponent<Transform>();
            batteryFill = new Image[4];
            batteryCount = batteryFill.Length - 1;

            for (int n = 0; n < batteryFill.Length; n++)
            {
                batteryFill[n] = battery.GetChild(n).GetComponent<Image>();
                batteryFill[n].enabled = false;
            }       //Добавление слотов в батарейку и скрытие их, т.к. при старте сцены фанарик выключен

            battery.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;  //Отключение видимости контура батарейки

            dischargeTime = 3;
            rechargeTime = 0.5f;
        }

        public void Start() { SetActiveFlashlight(false); }   //При старте сцены фонарик должен быть выключен

        public void Update() { if (!Enabled) return; }        //Если контроллер не активен, выходим из Update

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (_light.enabled == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine("Discharge");

                if (batteryFill[0].color == Color.red)
                {
                    SetActiveFlashlight(false);

                    StartCoroutine("Recharge");
                }
            }
            else if (_light.enabled == false || batteryFill[batteryCount].enabled == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine("Recharge");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Методы

        /// <summary>
        /// Включение/выключение фанарика _light
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Значение вкл(true)/выкл(false)</param>
        private void SetActiveFlashlight(bool value) { _light.enabled = value; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Разряд батареек
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IEnumerator Discharge()
        {
            batteryFill[batteryCount].color = Color.Lerp(batteryFill[batteryCount].color, Color.red, dischargeTime * Time.deltaTime);

            if (batteryFill[batteryCount].color == Color.red)
            {
                batteryFill[batteryCount].enabled = false;
                batteryCount--;
                Debug.Log(batteryCount);
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Зарядка батареек
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IEnumerator Recharge()
        {
            while (batteryCount < batteryFill.Length)
            {
                batteryFill[batteryCount].enabled = true;
                batteryFill[batteryCount].color = Color.Lerp(batteryFill[batteryCount].color, Color.green, rechargeTime * Time.deltaTime);

                if (batteryFill[batteryCount].color == Color.green && batteryCount < batteryFill.Length-1)
                    batteryCount++;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        public override void On()
        {
            if (Enabled) return;        //Если контроллер включен еще раз его не включаем
            base.On();
            SetActiveFlashlight(true);

            battery.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            foreach (Image block in batteryFill)
                block.enabled = true;
        }

        public override void Off()
        {
            if (!Enabled) return;       //Если контроллер выключен еще раз его не выключаем
            base.Off();
            SetActiveFlashlight(false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Собственно, все работает, когда в проекте нет объекта с именем "Battery". Поэтому и решил, что проблема именно в `Awake()` функции на этапе поиска.

Comment: Крайне не советую использовать `Find`. Создаёт костыли в коде.

Comment: Используйте лучше ссылки на объект

Answer (score 0):

```
GameObject Battery = GameObject.Find("Battery");
if (Battery != null)
    battery = Battery.GetComponent<Transform>();
```

Но вообще `Find` это отвратительная функция и с точки зрения производительности, архитектуры кода, целостности и т.д. и т.п. Ей нельзя пользоваться.

Если объект на сцене только одни, очень просто:

```
public class Battery : MonoBehavour {
    public static Battery main;

    private void Awake () {
        Battery = this;
    }
}
// ..... ..... .....
if (Battery.main != null) // Доступ откуда угодно
   Battery.main...;
```

Если не один, то нужен статический менеджер хранящий массив.

И никаких поисков по именам, только прямые ссылки.

Comment: А как тогда? Если я эту функцию ни к чему не привязываю и мне нужно найти этот объект?

Comment: @DeadLord если объект постоянный прикрепите через инспектор, если создаёте во время игры тогда и привязайте.

Comment: В том и вопрос. Как `создаёте во время игры тогда и привязайте`